# Why does destructuring work for walk but not postwalk in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, nested, nested-lists, clojure.walk

I can walk the top-level of the following map using `walk` in Clojure:

```
(use 'clojure.walk)
(walk (fn [[k v]] (println (type k) k v)) identity {:a 1 :b {:c 3}})
```

Result:

```
clojure.lang.Keyword :b {:c 3}
clojure.lang.Keyword :a 1
{}
```

(This works in a very similar way to `map`)

But when I use `postwalk` - it blows up trying to do destructuring:

```
(postwalk (fn [[k v]] (println (type k) k v)) {:a 1 :b {:c 3}})
```

Result:

```
UnsupportedOperationException nth not supported on this type: Keyword  clojure.lang.RT.nthFrom (RT.java:857)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe looking at what happens when you postwalk can shed some light into your issues.

```
user=> (postwalk println {:a 1 :b {:c 3}})
:a
1
[nil nil]
:b
:c
3
[nil nil]
{}
[nil nil]
{}
nil
user=>
```